# Sending a asp form with outlook email

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a form in asp.net c#, enter submit, it will be sent using outlook.

```
<label>Name: </label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<label>Age: </label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: You can use as `<a href="mailto:user@example.com?
subject=MessageTitle&amp;
body=Message Content">
Contact Us</a>`. It will open configured outlook with your content

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible.

The Outlook is on your client's computer, while the server-side code executes on the server.

There is one option - you can use the `mailto:` protocol. It definitely works with `<a href="mailto:hi@sample.com">Mail me!</a>`, and it might work with a (custom) form too:

```
<form action="mailto:name@domain.com" method="get">
 Subject: <input name="subject" /><br />
 Message: <br />
 <textarea name="body" />
</form>
```

But in ASP.NET WebForms, you've got one global form, so this will not work.

However, you most likely don't want to do that anyway. For one, there's no telling if your clients use an e-mail client at all. Second, it shows your own e-mail address to bots, so you're bound to get tons of spam rather soon. Third, this completely avoids any server side code you might want to e.g. record the e-mail or some such.